# Replacing string in a file by bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

How to replace a string in a file by bash variable, please

I tried

```
  i="1"
  sed -i 's/%q/0$i/g' file
  sed -i 's/%q/0"$i"/g' file
```

There is `0$i or 0"$i"` in the file instead of 01. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script as follow:

```bash
i="1"
sed -i "s/%q/0$i/g" file
sed -i "s/%q/0\"$i\"/g" file
```

and remember: the shell variables substitution does not happen inside single quotes. ;)